# How to select/count all records which happened in the last 2 hours? - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, time, intervals

In MYSQL i have DATE and TIME seperated. I need to count how many times one ip failed to login in the last 2 hours. If he failed too many times, then he can't login for the next 2 hours.

I just don't know which statement is the correct one (maybe none of the 2 below).

```
SELECT COUNT(`ip`) AS count_failed_logins FROM `failed_logins` WHERE `time`=TIME(CURTIME()+Interval 2 hour)
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(`ip`) AS count_failed_logins FROM `failed_logins` WHERE `time`=TIMEDIFF(CURTIME()+Interval 2 hour)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do :

```
SELECT COUNT(`ip`) FROM `failed_logins` WHERE `time` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR);
```

Comment: Damn it, just wrote that but with COUNT(*) instead of `ip` :)

Comment: But will this work correct? because `time` holds only the time (13:00:18). The date is not included. Or would it be better if i would store a datetime instead of date and time separately?

Comment: @povilasp it's my fault, i forgot it when i first posted this topic and edited it right after.

Comment: You should change the field type to datetime, unless the table is truncated every day, otherwise your user won't be able to login the next days within those 2 hours.

Comment: Exactly what i thought. Thank you for the help! I think that i will use the datetime field type.

Comment: One more quick question... What's the command to get the CURDATETIME?

Comment: NOW(), you have the doc to help you : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: Thank you! So now if i change the field type to DATETIME can i still use the statement which you posted above? with the DATE_SUB() in it?